# Difference between CSS centering methods. Which is better?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently wondering what is the difference between the following methods of centering a "wrapper" in CSS.

Method 1:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Method 2:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;

    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

From what I can see through some of my previous projects, they produce the same effect. "Method 2" is something I found on a youtube video whilst "Method 1" is from what I previously learned.

I simply want to know which is better, if possible. Though I wouldn't mind new methods as well! Anything that can help, I'll take. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Probably you want to define *better*? This sounds like it's looking for opinions.

Comment: the centering is done by setting left and right margin to auto. Both methods use the same technique (trough a different syntax). So are you asking which syntax is better?

Comment: My initial question was answered but for some reason that person deleted their answer shortly after. My second question is looking for opinions, I'll admit. Is that wrong?

Comment: The second one looks weird in my eyes:
The first one is the common method i'd say, never seen the sencond one

Comment: @VikingNM may I suggest you restore your (correct) answer? You'll get my vote ;-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with looking for opinions. SO just isn't the place for it...

Comment: This got a bit out of hand, I'm simply asking what is the _best_ way to center a "wrapper".

Comment: `flexbox` is the "new" way of handling layout and can center your content with ease. Probably the way to go for new applications, and definitely worth investigating!

Comment: @Pevara So with `flexbox`, I can simply horizontally align it using `justify-content: center;` ?

Comment: Yes. This is a great reference btw: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Pevara I actually have this site and that page bookmarked, just haven't really looked into it.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 would be the preferred method, although, to make it responsive you should  make

```
width:100%;
max-width:960px;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

is the shorthand for

```
margin-top: 0; 
margin-bottom: 0; 
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

Your second example is equal to

```
margin-top: 0; 
margin-bottom: -4em; 
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

, so it's *not* the same as your first example (unless there would be an inheritated `margin-bottom` of `-4em`

But both will center a block element. However, the `bottom-margin: -4em` will cause subsequent elements to overlap this element by 4em...

Note: All this only applies to horizontal centering. There is *no* vertical centering in both methods.